# Completing a tree to a 2-connected outerplanar graph

Tags: graph-theory, trees, embeddings, planar-graphs

Let $T$ be a given (finite) tree.

**Question 1:** Is it always possible to add edges to $T$ to obtain a $2$-connected outerplanar supergraph $G$?

**Question 2:** If the answer to Question #1 is negative, can the trees for which it is possible be characterized?

**Question 3( Defect form of Question 1):** Let $T$ be a *rooted* tree with root vertex $v_{0} \in V(T)$. Is it always possible to add edges to $T$ to obtain a $2$-connected planar graph $G$ with a plane embedding in which $v_{0}$ is the only internal vertex?

Comment: Any tree is already outerplanar, right?

Comment: @SamHopkins Yes, of course. I meant a 2-connected one. Many thanks for noticing the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Pick an arbitrary vertex to be the root. Consider the sequence of vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ produced by a pre-order traversal of the rooted tree, adding edges $v_i - v_{i+1}$ where they don't already exist. Finally, add an edge back from the last vertex to the root, if it doesn't already exist. This cycle defines the outer face and gives 2-connectivity.

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice! Do you know of a reference where this is discussed perhaps?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, no, sorry. I'm sure it's not original, but I came up with it independently.